# Remove elementor header and display default theme header

Tags: functions, custom-header

I am using Elementor pro and I am using Tabor wordpress theme(Here theme link: https://themebeans.com/themes/tabor/). I create custom footer within elementor pro and I noticed that the default theme header is disappear. So I have to create custom header with elementor pro. But any how I want to keep the default theme header.
Can you anyone help me?